# Wasserstein distance between hyperplane and cube

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, concentration-of-measure, optimal-transport

Let $\mu$ be the uniform measure on the cube $Q = [-1,1]^n$, and $\nu$ be the uniform measure on the surface
$$
V = \{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in Q \mid \sum x_i = 0\}.
$$
I am curious about Wasserstein distance between $\mu$ and $\nu$, using the $l^\infty$ distance on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

That is, I would like a bound on
$$
\sup_{\|f\|_{Lip}=1} |\mathbb{E}_\mu f - \mathbb{E}_\nu f|.
$$ 
I expect that the distance is on the order of $n^{-1/2}$ based on the following two calculations.  First, one guess is that the function $S(x)=\frac{1}{n}|\sum x_i|$ would be close to optimizing the above supremum, and 
$$
|\mathbb{E}_\mu S - \mathbb{E}_\nu S| \leq Cn^{-1/2}.
$$

The second heuristic follows from the fact that if $x\in Q$ is sampled according to $\mu$, then with high probability $|\sum x_i| \leq Cn^{1/2}$, so by nudging each of the coefficients by an amount $n^{-1/2}$ it should be possible to land on the plane.  This gives a transport map from $\mu$ to a measure supported on $V$ that has cost roughly $n^{-1/2}$.  The problem is that the transported measure is not the same as $\nu$, so this does not constitute a proof.